# How would I populate an array with upper and lowercase letters as well as numbers?

Tags: arrays, perl, data-structures

I'm trying to print ALL possibilities for upper and lower case alpha characters mixed with numeric characters for 4 digits in Perl.    Can someone please help me the logic is eluding my feeble mind!

Here is my code:

```
use Number::Nary;

my ($enc) = n_codec(join '', 0..9, 'A'..'Z', 'a'..'z'); 

for (my $n = 0, $str = $enc->($n); $str ne '00001' ; $n++, $str = $enc->($n)) {
   print $str; 
}
```

Comment: What do you mean, doesn't work? The code you posted works fine

Comment: That said, I agree the code is terrible. You should take it to the code review sister site. That you used `$c = join ',', a..z, A..Z, 0..9; @loadarray = glob "{$c}" x 1;` instead of subset `@loadarray = ( a..z, A..Z, 0..9 );` is barely scratching the surface.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a pretty straightforward way to do it:

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl

use strict;
use warnings;

my @chars = (0..9, 'A'..'Z', 'a'..'z');

for my $a (@chars) {
  for my $b (@chars) {
    for my $c (@chars) {
      for my $d (@chars) {
        print join('', $a, $b, $c, $d) . "\n";
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This will do as you ask. It uses a custom subroutine `inc_base_62`, which will add 1 to a base 62 string consisting of digits and upper- and lower-case letters. Using this in a loop that starts with `0000` will create all possible values up to `zzzz` and then cycle back to `0000` when the loop terminates.

Note that there are nearly 15 million such combinations, and it will take a few minutes to print all these values (note that Perl will cope with an array of 15 million four-character strings just fine). If you want to check with something more manageable then try starting at `00`, which will produce just 3,844 combinations.

```
use strict;
use warnings;

my $s = '0000';

while () {
  print "$s\n";
  $s = inc_base_62($s);
  last unless $s =~ /[^0]/;
}


sub inc_base_62 {
  my @word = unpack '(A1)*', shift;
  my %special = ( '9' => 'A', 'Z' => 'a', 'z' => '0' );

  for ( reverse @word ) {
    if ( exists $special{$_} ) {
      $_ = $special{$_};
      next if $_ eq '0';
    }
    else {
      ++$_;
    }
    last;
  }
  join '', @word 
}
```